# check if a string contains a numeric value

Tags: c#, string, int

I am trying to check if a string contains a numeric value, if it doesnt return to a label if it does then I would like to show the main window. How can this be done?

```
If (mystring = a numeric value)
            //do this:
            var newWindow = new MainWindow();
            newWindow.Show();
If (mystring = non numeric)
            //display mystring in a label
            label1.Text = mystring;

else return error to message box
```

Comment: does non-numeric mean no numbers, or just "not all numbers"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Int32 intValue;
if (Int32.TryParse(mystring, out intValue)){
  // mystring is an integer
}
```

Or, if it's a decimal number:

```
Double dblValue;
if (Double.TryParse(mystring, out dblValue)){
  // mystring has a decimal number
}
```

Some examples, BTW, can be [found here](http://ideone.com/nOAbu).

```
Testing foo:
Testing 123:
    It's an integer! (123)
    It's a decimal! (123.00)
Testing 1.23:
    It's a decimal! (1.23)
Testing $1.23:
    It's a decimal! (1.23)
Testing 1,234:
    It's a decimal! (1234.00)
Testing 1,234.56:
    It's a decimal! (1234.56)
```

A couple more I've tested:

```
Testing $ 1,234:                      // Note that the space makes it fail
Testing $1,234:
    It's a decimal! (1234.00)
Testing $1,234.56:
    It's a decimal! (1234.56)
Testing -1,234:
    It's a decimal! (-1234.00)
Testing -123:
    It's an integer! (-123)
    It's a decimal! (-123.00)
Testing $-1,234:                     // negative currency also fails
Testing $-1,234.56:
```

Comment: so double doesnt check if its just one number only a decimal?

Comment: As an interesting aside, `Double.TryParse` can handle commas in a number but `Int32.TryParse` cannot.

Comment: Never knew that about the commas. Seems like a strange design choice since as a 000's separator they are equally valid or invalid in floating point and integer numbers. If anything, it would make more sense to only allow them in integers since there's a culture-specific ambiguity with FP numbers! Really odd.

Comment: @jamietre: Yes, it is indeed odd. I was also surprised, when I kept going, that negative currency also fails. Why they accept one method and not the next is...odd.

Comment: @Kirsty: if you only care if it's a number then use `double.TryParse` as an integer is also a valid double. If you require that the number also be an integer, then use `int.TryParse`

Answer (score 6):

use TryParse.

```
double val;
if (double.TryParse(mystring, out val)) {
    ..
} else { 
    ..
}
```

This will work for strings that translate directly to a number. If you need to worry about stuff like $ and , also, then you'll need to do a little more work to clean it up first.

Answer (score 2):

```
double value;
if (double.tryParse(mystring, out value))
{
        var newWindow = new MainWindow();
        newWindow.Show();
}
else
{
    label1.Text = mystring;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply reference Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll, then do the following:

```
if (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Information.IsNumeric(mystring))
{
    var newWindow = new MainWindow();
    newWindow.Show();
}
else
{
    label1.Text = mystring;
}
```

*The VB one actually performs better, as it doesn't throw an exception for every failed conversion.*

See: [Exploring IsNumeric for C#](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringIsNumericForC.aspx)

Comment: using the VB library is sort of interesting, but that article must have been written before TryParse. There's no reason to use try/catch to test something for being numeric in C#.

Comment: Yea, I'm sure it was. It is an interesting solution though and that's why I thought I'd share it (as being a VB guy myself, I use it all the time).

Comment: Honestly I had never even given it a thought before. I probably would be hesitant to do so in anything more than a one-off just because it's another dependency, but it's a tool in your toolbox to be sure.

Comment: I wouldn't reference `VB` to check if a string is numeric or not. there are so many other ways `X.tryParse, Regex, LINQ, foreach` some are better than the others, ** but there is just no need to use C# little brother - VB.** for this task(or should I say for tasks.)

Comment: @gdoron - It's simply an alternative solution. It all comes down to preference.

Comment: I +1'd you both though, as you both have functionally working answers that accomplish his task =D

Answer (score 0):

You may use a boolean to judge if the string contains numeric chars.

```
public bool GetNumberFromStr(string str)
    {
        string ss = "";
        foreach (char s in str)
        {
            int a = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(s), out a))
                ss += a;
        }
        if ss.Length >0
           return true;
        else
           return false;
    }
```

Comment: Using TryParse(Convert...)) is about the most inefficient way I can think of to test a char for whether or not it's a digit.

Answer (score 0):

Try taking the Label's caption into a string and 
use  `Int.TryParse()` method to decide whether text is integer or string. the method will return true if yes , else it will return false. Code will be like :

```
if (Int.TryParse(<string> , out Num) == True)
{
   // is numeric
}
else
{
   //is string
}
```

where Num will contain your integer value if conversion is a success

Answer (score 0):

A good example of method that will do this can be found at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

There's even some code doing something almost exactly what you want.  You can use a Int32.TryParse(string) if you're expecting integer values.  If you anticipate doubles, use Double.TryParse(string).